# Angular character encoding issue contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using a combination of Angular and a contenteditable div to try and create a two way binding that I can later use an Angular controller to manipulate the data. Everything has been working great, with the exception of certain html characters that make there way into the model.

For example, when I type `&` I get `&amp;` when there is a nonbreaking space I get `nbsp;`

How do I modify the contenteditable directive to clean the encoded values out and only keep the unencoded versions?

Plunkr here - http://plnkr.co/edit/ToylycanYcMJq15K36Yd?p=preview

You will see in the contenteditable directive I have this line:
`html = element.html().replace('&nbsp;','');`

To try and replace the `&nbsp;` values, but it's having no affect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can do something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/S4eTSI3W3VWh1dtsJp93), but I think you would be better using `input` or `textarea` for the same. According to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) AngularJS Models support only `input`, `select` or `textarea`.

Also there is an [open](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/528) issue for the same problem that you are facing.

Here is the code if you intend to use contenteditable div:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);

myApp.controller('chatterCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('comment', function(){
    if($scope.comment != undefined){
      $scope.comment = unescape($scope.comment);
    }
  }, true);
}]);
```